# Swift - Restriction of accessing user's documents

Tags: swift, apple-pdfkit

I have table view and a plus button, when button tapped it present a document picker, I select files then return to main screen.

I store files by their urls, and present them via pdfkit framework.

The problem is, after a while document selected, i guess system restrict the accessing to that file.
URL is like this: "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/SOMENUMBERS/tmp/NAME/xxx.pdf"
How can I get them to last longer?